# SharePoint linking an Excel document to a List

Tags: excel, sharepoint, spservices

I have an excel document which is sent daily to me.

I have a SharePoint List that is then update daily by me with all the excel documents information (complete overwrite each day).

The list is used to generate a few calculation and metrics reports.

Is there a way to associate the List and Excel document together so I can just overwrite an excel document in a document library and the list will populate? I know I can create a List from an excel document but that is only a one time process as far as I can tell.

I have excel services turned on so I can view the document in the browser.

Currently, I use a query like this to query the List. If this can be changed to query the excel document that is another viable option.

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='date'/></OrderBy></Query>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=<fieldName>/></ViewFields>",
        listName: <list id>,
        completefunc: <functionname>
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking about on the web the two options I can find are:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134054/Restoring-Two-Way-Synchronization-on-SharePoint-Li
2. Open your sharepoint list in Access with two-way syncronisation enabled. Use VBA to import your data from excel into access, run an
   update/insert (upsert...) query against your imported data to update
   the sharepoint list and with luck, voilà

Answer (score 1):

Just a curious question, you said you need the list for reporting purpose, can't you use the same excel for reporting/charting. So you generate pivot charts and table with data. When you receive new excel data you just update the excel with new data and upload it in sharepoint.
Than use Excel viewer webpart to render it on page!

Comment: There's a service we use that generates the excel documents. The documents can be generated with some charts. The excel document is essentially a database dump from the service. If we were to build the charts in excel the data would need to be transferred over to document with the calculations built in each day. So what we did was create a page on SharePoint with some highchart.js libraries and generate a dashboard from that report along with other reports that managers would need to see.

Comment: i still believe you should be able to do all the calculation in excel with calculated columns. Also, if you are getting the excel via service then you can use that a source of data in separate excel plotting charts in there and then always refresh this excel and upload Sorry if am taking you to other direction, but i believe there always simple solution for complicated issues:)

Comment: Thanks I will consider this if the other options don't scale further than we need them too.